# How to create nice text depth\shadow effect? (HTML)

Tags: javascript, html, css, text

I need some JS class or CSS method to create from any text such text with shadow like [on this web page...](http://www.iconsweets.com/)

Page screen:

[image: screen from Yummygum site]
<sub>(source: [narod.ru](http://superior0.narod.ru/deepText.jpg))</sub>

I need It to work in IE 6,7,8 Chrome 4, FF 3, etc

Comment: That color scheme makes my eyes bleed! And I'm usually someone who loves bright colors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspect element says:
`text-shadow:0 1px 0 #3B3B3B;`

More on text-shadow http://www.quirksmode.org/css/textshadow.html http://www.css3.info/preview/text-shadow/

Comment: what browser do you use for element's Inspection?

Comment: firefox with firebug addon. IIRC chrome has a built in similar developer toolbar, or something like that.

Comment: in Chrome (on Ubuntu, at least) the web-developer tools have the shortcut 'shift + ctrl + i'

Comment: @ricebowl +1 and cheers for that, now all I have to do is remember it :D

Answer (score 1):

Make use of the [CSS3 `text-shadow` property](http://www.css3.info/preview/text-shadow/). This is however not supported by all webbrowsers. You may want to consider the [jQuery TextShadow plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/textshadow) to cover the unsupported unobtrusively.

Answer (score 0):

You can create that effect with css3's `text-shadow` property.

**Example:**

```
p.test {
    text-shadow: #6374AB 20px -12px 2px;
}
```

.

**Quick Preview:**

[image]

Of course, you will have to modify the values as per your needs.

**Note:** This property belongs to CSS3, something not supported by **Internet Explorer** yet. However, most of the other modern browsers support CSS3.

Answer (score 0):

If you **must** use IE6, you have to use old hacks (or as always - abuse JQuery, since it kicks ass). Something like this:

```
<style>
  .text1{ color: white }
  .shadow1{ color: silver; position: relative; right: 1px; bottom: 1px }
  .shadow1{ color: black; position: relative; right: 2px; bottom: 2px }
</style>
<div class="text1">Text shadow</div>
<div class="shadow1">Text shadow</div>
<div class="shadow2">Text shadow</div>
```

Very, very old school. Be careful not to stick it inside a table in an HTML4.01 transitional page ;-)